# How to hide default links in quick launch

Tags: 2010, quick-launch

Does anyone know how I can hide the Libraries and Discussions from the quick launch shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage navigation for a SharePoint site, you must have the Full Control or Design permission level for the site. You have one of these permission levels if you can access the Sites Settings page for the site and you see the **Navigation** command under **Look and Feel** (on non-publishing sites, you will see the **Quick Launch** and **Top link bar** commands under **Look and Feel** instead of **Navigation**).

1. To go to the Site Navigation Settings page, do one of the following:

   - On the **Site Actions** menu, click **Site Settings**.
   - On the **Site Actions** menu, point to **Site Settings**, and then Click **Modify All Site Settings**.
2. In the **Look and Feel** column, click **Navigation**.

**Note: -**   The **Navigation** command appears under **Look and Feel** only if the publishing features are enabled for your site and you have the Full Control or Design permission level.

If you find any difficulties than please follow [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-navigation-items-on-the-Site-Navigation-Settings-page-6ad7a02c-8724-4a51-9972-dc4537566cb2)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to show/ hide the links from the quick launch,

1. manual way is , Go to Site Settings->Look and feel -> Quick launch and add/delete the quick launch links.
   for more information : 
   http://www.endusersharepoint.com/EUSP2010/2010/06/04/navigating-sharepoint-2010-part-2-the-quick-launch/
2. CSS is also an option if you want to hide it dynamically.
3. Script/Powershell also can help

Comment: 1a. Go to Site Settings->Look and feel -> Navigation if the publishing infrastructure feature is enabled

Comment: Yes publishing feature should be enable. Thanks @EricAlexander

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. You can try this below option.

Go to Site Setting -> Look and Feel -> Tree View there you can set